# Rails button without form

Tags: ruby-on-rails

As far as I can tell button_to is for submitting a form. Is there something in rails dedicated for buttons that just run some javascript on the client without sending anything to the server?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to run only javascript on client side, you can add plain html button and call some function to run your required javascript, by binding an event to that button. You dont need to use rails code at all.

Answer (score 0):

That has nothing to do with rails but rather HTML.

You can always place normal HTML markup (like a `<button>` or a `<a>` on the form and make it trigger some action in JavaScript)

Sample:

```
<%= form_for(@post) do |f| %>
  ...
  <button id="clicktrigger">Click Me!</button>
<% end %>
```

Comment: actually, the default behavior of `<button>` in html is to be a submit button, so yod'd need to specify the `type="button"` for your example to work properly.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:

you can call javascript function using onclick. It will not submit a form.

```
<%= submit_tag "Test me!", :type => 'button', :onclick => 'alert("It works!")' %>
```